# JVM threads count decreased after Java 11 migration causing high latency

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, jvm, java-11

I migrated the Application that was running in Java 8 and Spring Boot version 2.0.8.RELEASE to Java 11 and Spring Boot version 2.7.11.

Migration was successful and the application is working fine but I could see the JVM threads were reduced a lot and also able to see the undertow server queue was high after migration and due to this, there was an increase in latency. Kubernetes pods were restarting during the high latency time the CPU usage was also high.

Comment: I suggest that you start by finding out why the pods were restarting.

Comment: Which kind of threads were reduced? Is it a specific thread pool?

Comment: Recent Java version obtain more information about their run environment when running in a container. It is possible that it uses/reports a lower CPU count because of the requests/limits you configured for your pod, this in turn may lead to libraries using a lower number of threads for thread pools and such. You may need to manually override this by instructing Java to assume a higher CPU count with `-XX:ActiveProcessorCount`, e.g, `-XX:ActiveProcessorCount=4` to assume four CPUs.

Comment: Alternatively, find out if you can configure Undertow manually to use a higher thread count instead of deriving it from the CPU count.

Comment: If I manually increase the undertow thread count will it not affect the performance of the application?

Comment: Changing the amount of threads will likely affect the performance of your application. But isn't that what you want?

Comment: The configuration for requests/limits hasn't changed. It is the same as before migration.

Comment: The ideal configuration may be different with different Spring/Java versions.

Comment: Is there any formula to see how many threads I can increase to? for now, the undertow threads are 16 which is a default value.

Comment: I guess you need to try out different values and see what works best. There are formulas like `number of threads = number of cores * estimated IO time / estimated CPU time` but there are also some issues with that (i.e. at some point, you'll reach OS or memory limitations when creating too many threads)

Comment: Is there a way to find the configuration for the Java version?
Will the docker image also impact the CPU count?

Comment: Try it and see what works best.

Comment: _"The configuration for requests/limits hasn't changed."_. You upgraded from Java 8, and since - I believe - Java 10, Java will get more information about the container it's running in, and use that to calculate an estimate of the equivalent processor count, where previously it would likely use the actual processor count of the underlying machine. If a threadpool is configured using that processor count, you will now get a smaller thread pool.